# class-validator is wrong with nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I am using nestjs and class validator to validate a parameter of the type string of a controller endpoint but although the parameter is of the correct type it throws me an error as if it were incorrect.I also use typescript

pokemon.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Param, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PokemonService } from './pokemon.service';
import { PokemonTypeDto } from './dto/pokemon-type.dto';

@Controller('pokemons')
export class PokemonController {
  constructor(private readonly pokemonService: PokemonService) {}

  @Get('types/:type')
  async getTotalPokemonsByType(@Param('type') type: PokemonTypeDto) {
    return this.pokemonService.getTotalPokemonsByType(type);
  }
}
```

pokemon-type.dto.ts

```
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class PokemonTypeDto {
  @IsString()
  readonly type: string;
}
```

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      }
    })
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

ts.config.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

the endpoint is the following: http://localhost:3000/pokemons/types/:type

example of a request with the correct type: http://localhost:3000/pokemons/types/normal

example of a request with the wrong type: http://localhost:3000/pokemons/types/123

in both cases it returns the following error:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "type must be a string"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

and in the first example it should not return that error, only with the second example.

What do I have to do to make it work correctly?

Comment: When not using validation - does the received DTO look correct?

Comment: If I comment out the "IsString()" of the dto, it does not validate anything and the "type" parameter always passes even if it is invalid

Answer (score 1):

`@Param('type')` means you expect the `type` in the URL parameters to be a `PokemonTypeDto`. What you probably mean to do instead is `@Param() { type }: PokemonTypeDto`

Comment: As I understood, you want the code to look like this: ```async getTotalPokemonsByType(@Param() { type }: PokemonTypeDto) {
     return this.pokemonService.getTotalPokemonsByType(type);
   }``` . If I leave it like this, it doesn't validate anything and any parameter is valid even when it's invalid.

Comment: What are you considering invalid here? URL parameters always come in as strings, and you have `@Get('types/:type')` so as long as you always send a `GET /pokemons/types/something` it's a valid string and there will never be an error. Even `GET /pokemons/types/42` will have `type` as the string `'42'` so it will pass

Comment: Yeah, what Jay said.  @LucianoPulido it kind of sounds like maybe you want an enum, which would express the strings that are allowed, and you'd then use that as your type and use the `IsEnum` decorator.

Comment: Either `@IsEnum()` or an `@IsIn()` if you don't want to touch Typescript enums

Comment: @JayMcDoniel IsEnum works with plain ole objects too.

Comment: @incutonez that's because enums are plain objects after transpilation. They're essentially key value maps with the all `key:value` and `value:key` pairs